# Is "good for you" or "good on you" meant as sarcasm in English?

Tags: phrases, expressions

In Swedish, kids (at least a few decades ago, when I was a kid) sarcastically say:

> Kul för dig!

This literally means:

> Fun for you!

Or, more clearly:

> That's good... for you!! (But what's it to *me*?!)

Alternatively:

> Oh yeah? How... fun... for you. I'm so... happy... for you... and I'm not jealous at all.

In English, there's a very common phrase:

> Good for you!

Or:

> Good on you!

Maybe it's just because I think of the Swedish phrase, but whenever an American says this, it always comes off as sarcasm to me. As if they really aren't saying that something is "good", but rather that:

> I guess that's good for **you**[, you boastful little]...

But maybe in English, it's genuinely a way to express that you are happy for somebody else and their success, or whatever was said prior?

Comment: I think *Good **on** you!* might have some currency in Australia/NZ relaxed conversational contexts, but it's not exactly "mainstream" compared to *Good **for** you!* As to how often ***either*** version represents sincere congratulations, and how often it's just sarcastically dismissive - that's entirely a matter of ***context and opinion.***

Comment: It's hard to praise (short of singing hymns), and a lot of attempts come across as sarcasm, ridiculously understated, antiquated or insincere. I try to give back-handed compliments. These often backfire and come across as insults. But then again, a lot of 'compliments' are meant as insults, and tone doesn't always differentiate.

Comment: "Good for you" is usually taken to mean approval. "I've taken this up with my manager." Reply "Good for you!"

Comment: *Any* sentence can be used sarcastically. It's a matter of context and delivery (intonation).

Comment: The congratulatory and sarcastic aspects of this phrase may sometimes be impossible to disentangle, even taking into account the tone and the context, because a feeling of joy at somebody's accomplishment may be mixed with light jealousy in the very mind of the person using the phrase.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I've also heard "Good on you!" used frequently in Ireland.

Answer (score 3):

"Good for you" is often used sarcastically, but can also mean "You did well" or "That is well-deserved and I'm glad for you." "Good on you" is almost always intended as a compliment, I believe. But a sinister person who is generally sarcastic could say virtually anything sarcastically or at least with a secret sneer.